# Buildpack Lifecycle to Docker Image in Cloudfoundry

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy a docker image to a cloud application that was originally created with a build pack, however I am receiving a "Docker cannot be configured for a buildpack lifecycle app" response.

Are there steps I need to take to allow the application to accept the docker image now?

Thank you for any help!

Current manifest.yml:

```
applications:
- name: server-dev
  memory: 512M
  disk_quota: 512M
  docker:
     image: adambuckingham/srt-api:S11.0.0
  instances: 1
  env:
    NODE_ENV: dev
  services:
    - postgres-dev
```

My feature flags:

```
name                                          state
app_bits_upload                               enabled
app_scaling                                   enabled
diego_docker                                  enabled
env_var_visibility                            enabled
hide_marketplace_from_unauthenticated_users   disabled
private_domain_creation                       enabled
resource_matching                             enabled
route_creation                                enabled
route_sharing                                 enabled
service_instance_creation                     enabled
service_instance_sharing                      enabled
set_roles_by_username                         enabled
space_developer_env_var_visibility            enabled
space_scoped_private_broker_creation          enabled
task_creation                                 enabled
unset_roles_by_username                       enabled
user_org_creation                             disabled
```